# Can I create calendar heatmap using highchart plugin on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, calendar, vuetify.js, heatmap

[image]

I would like to create a chart like the picture above using the Highcharts plugin in Vuejs.
I'd do some research but couldn't find anyway to make this type of heatmap chart.

Comment: Hi @Kingsley Yong, You can build that chart with basic heatmap. You need to only use a right data and draw the separating lines by `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer You can start from: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zpadv513/